# Display Java List values in Javascript alert

Tags: javascript, java

I have a Java list whose values I need to display in Javascript.

Here is my Java code to populate the List:

```
List<CoordinateVO> coordinateList = new ArrayList<CoordinateVO>();

for (Iterator iterator2 = cordinates.iterator(); iterator2.hasNext();) {

Adcoordinate object = (Adcoordinate) iterator2.next();

if(object!=null){

    CoordinateVO co = new CoordinateVO(object.getLatitude(),object.getLongitude());
    coordinateList.add(co);
    }
}
```

Now I want to display values of CoordinateList in Javascript Dialog Box.
Is there any way out to do this ?

Comment: How are you getting your Java code to output to a webpage?

Comment: Im using DWR to get the Java VO object to display in Jquery Dialog Box , Now the challenge is the that , there is List in VO object whose values  I need have to display in Jquery Dialog Box .
My Jsp code is here 
<sj:a href="#" onclick="getAdvertiserDetails('%{ad_id}');"
     openDialog="advertiserDetailsDialog">
function getAdvertiserDetails(id) {

  advertiserDetails.getAdvertisementDetails(id, setAdvertiserDetails);
 }

 function setAdvertiserDetails(data) {
if (!data.keyword) {
body += "<tr><td valign='top'><b>Keyword:</b></td><td>"
     + data.keyword + "</td></tr>";
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution , 
I converted the `java.util.List` into Json Array in java code and then in Javascript I parse the Json Array .

Here is my Java Code

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(coordinateList); //  List Conversion to Json Array 
dataVO.setCoordinateArray(json);
```

In Javascript

```
<script>
var myObject=JSON.parse(dataVO.adScript); 
var index;
for (index = 0; index < myObject.length; ++index) {

     alert("Test Latitude "+myObject[index].latitude);

     alert("Test Longitude "+myObject[index].longitude);

}
</script>
```